# Can't scrape reviews from multiple pages and it's only scraping reviews before (new line spacing) spacing

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler, scrapy-shell

Thank you in advance for your time. I really appreciate that.

I am trying to scrape product reviews, ratings and other info from amazon. Below is the code for the same. The issue I am getting is:

- The first page has 10 reviews.
- And in the crawled data all reviews are from these 10 customers only.
- 10 lines of reviews data and then a blank line, then again these 10 and so on. Total of 196 lines in the same way.
- Also if any review has 'ENTER' used in it by the customer for spacing then only text before spacing is there in the review. As highlighted in the image below in yellow.

Link to scrape - [https://www.amazon.com/product-reviews/B01DFKC2SO/ref=cm_cr_arp_d_viewpnt_lft?pageNumber=](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01DFKC2SO)

**My Code:**

```
import scrapy
 
 
class ReviewspiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
 
    name = 'reviewspider'
 
    allowed_domains = ["www.amazon.com"]
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.amazon.com/product-reviews/B01DFKC2SO/ref=cm_cr_arp_d_viewpnt_lft?pageNumber=']
 
    def parse(self, response):
        for review in response.xpath("//div[@id='cm_cr-review_list']/div"):
            yield {
                'Name': review.xpath('.//span[@class="a-profile-name"]/text()').get(),
                'Title': review.xpath('.//a[@data-hook="review-title"]/span/text()').get(),
                'Rating': review.xpath('.//span[@class="a-icon-alt"]/text()').get(),
                'Review': review.xpath('.//span[@data-hook="review-body"]/span/text()').get()
            }
 
        next_page = response.xpath(
            "//a[text()='Next page']").get()
        if next_page:
            yield response.follow(url=next_page, callback=self.parse)
```

**Output:**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5M28I.png)

Answer (score 2):

You have forgotten to select the href:

```
next_page = response.xpath("//a[text()='Next page']/@href").get()
```

You were joining the whole tag to the response.url, not the href.

As it goes to the part of the question of why the text is removed. The text is not removed, you are just not getting it, you are just getting the first part of the text. `text()` returns a plaint text, if there is a 
 it splits the text.

There are two options on how to fix it.
First is to use string function in the xpath for the span selector:

```
review.xpath('string(.//span[@data-hook="review-body"]/span)').get()
```

But I would not recommend it, as it removes only the tags in the selector. So the text will be without any separators between them (e.g. "I have two.I have so many..." nothing between "." and "I").

I would suggest to use `getall` method and get all of the plaint texts of the tag and then simply join them with the seperator you seem fit.

```
'\n'.join(review.xpath('.//span[@data-hook="review-body"]/span/text()').getall())
```

Comment: Hi Igor,  Thanks for answering. Could you please help answer the another part of the question "Also if any review has 'ENTER' used in it by the customer for spacing then only text before spacing is there in the review. As highlighted in the image below in yellow." 

And why there's an empty line created in the excel file after every page change.

Thanks for your help and time.

Comment: Hi @IgorDragushhak, Thanks for helping me with this. I really appreciate your time.
In addition, I am unclear about one thing that why I am not able to scrape all the available reviews. Is there any restriction that amazon put on scraping. 

Thanks for your help and time.